# How do I remove commas from an array of strings

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a list of arrays as so:

```
0: "1 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon"
1: "10 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon"
2: "11 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon"
3: "12 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon"
```

And I want to remove the commas in the middle:

```
 , , ,
```

I am using Lodash and looked at using `_.compact()` however this doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere.

Let me know your thoughts

Update

```
                var addressArray = getAddressData.data.Addresses;

                scope.items = _.compact(addressArray);

                console.log(scope.items);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with RegEx to remove extra commas.

```
arr.map(e => e.replace(/(,\s*)+/, ','));
```

ES5 Equivalent:

```
arr.map(function (e) {
    return e.replace(/(,\s*)+/, ',');
});
```

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jZ4mX3/1)

The regex `(,\s*)+` will search for one or more commas separated by any number of spaces between them.

```js
var arr = ["1 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon", "10 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon", "11 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon", "12 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon"];

arr = arr.map(e => e.replace(/(,\s*)+/, ', '));
console.log(arr);

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: I'm sorry i can't get your code to work.. var addressArray = getAddressData.data.Addresses.map(e => e.replace(/(,\s*)+/, ', '));

Comment: My gulp won't compile it

Comment: @MaxLynn Yes, that should work, if that is not working, create live demo on jsfiddle. Also, check if Arrow functions is supported or not.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for your help guys... I know there is loads of stuff online about this but it went straight over my head. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can split by coma, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) blanks and join.

```
var str = "1 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon";
var result = str.split(',').filter(x => x.trim()).join()
console.log(result); // 1 Trenchard Road, Saltford, Bristol, Avon
```

Notice: used ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`=>`) you can replace it with classical `function` if it does not work in your environment.

Full example with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
let arr = [
    '1 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon',
    '10 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon',
    '11 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon',
    '12 Trenchard Road, , , , Saltford, Bristol, Avon'
];

let result = arr.map(i => i.split(',').filter(x => x.trim()).join());
```

ES5 Equivalent:

```
var result = arr.map(function(i) {
    return i.split(',').filter(function(x) {
        return x.trim();
    }).join();
});
```

Comment: No need to check trimmed string with empty string as empty string is falsey, just use `.filter(x => x.trim())`.

Comment: Could you show me an example of it being looped through a for each?

Answer (score 0):

Use array filter function

```
["1 Trenchard Road", , , , "Saltford", "Bristol", "Avon"].filter(function(i){return i})
```

Comment: How will i loop through my array?

Comment: To loop through, you may use forEach for that

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the solution in JS :

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) { 
    if(arr[i].indexOf(',') > -1) { 
      console.log(arr[i].replace(/,/g,'')); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Does this make all my array items a array again?

Comment: @MaxLynn The below code will make all the array items an array again for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) { 
    if(arr[i].indexOf(',') > -1) { 
      arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/,/g,'');
    } 
}

Comment: If now u check the var arr..then u will get the list of arrays without the comma(,).. I hope this solution helps..